# Properties for application specific attributes in Android

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-titlebar

I want to center the application title/label in my Android app but I can't find a lot of documentation on how to set that property.  I have found a couple of posts saying that I can create a custom title bar and change the theme in my manifest but I just can't help thinking there is a simpler way to just center the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience documentation on this isn't great but I figured it out and I'll share. It's actually pretty simple.

Custom centered title bar on your activity:

Add two lines to your activity at the beginning of `onCreate()` so it looks like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.mytitle);
...
...
...

}
```

Now put mytitle.xml in your layout directory. This xml file should look something like this to center your title text:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/myTitle"
  android:textStyle="bold"
  android:textSize="15sp"
  android:text="My Custom Title Text"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
  android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
   />
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the label of any of your activities with the `android:label="@string/app_name"` in your manifest. You can do it in code too. I'm not sure what else you want

Comment: He's asking about centering the text, not setting the text.